# Can we use SEND THROTTLING to split and send email weekly?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a requirement as below to send an email to 7500 subscribers.

1. Email needs to be sent every Friday at 10 am IST, every week!
2. Email needs to be sent max to a 500 customers per DAY!
3. So the same email needs to be sent until all in the list are
   exhausted.

I am aware of the FILTERED DE feature to manually divide the audience into 15 segments of 500 each!

However, I am wondering if this requirement can be achieved via SEND THROTTLING? Can any one advise?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use Send Throttling for this use case. Why? because:

> The system begins processing the email send job at the start time you
>   specify. The send is not spread evenly between the start and end
>   times. The system continues sending during the specified time range
>   until the send is complete or the end time you specified is reached,
>   whichever comes first. **If the end time is reached before the send is
>   complete, the system will continue the send the *next day* at the same
>   start time.** This process continues until the send is complete.

The system will continue the send the next day. However, you need it to be sent every friday in a journey..

Your best bet is to segment your audience with a query and place it on an automation that inject those segments every friday ..

**OR**

Inject all your audience in a Journey and use a combinaison of Random Splits along with waits to throttle the sends on several paths.. However, random splits with low numbers are not very accurate..

Reference: [Send Throttle](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_throttle.htm&type=5)

Comment: +1 and my first thought was also Random Split in a JB